# Rationality condition for strongly $(k,0,3)$ regular graph

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, graph-theory

I am asked to show that if $G$ is an incomplete, strongly $(k,0,3)$ regular graph, then $|G| = n \in \{6,162\}$

Now I know the rationality condition here tells us that: $\frac{1}{2}(n-1 \pm \frac{3(n-1)-2k}{\sqrt{4k-3}}) \in \mathbb Z$

Given this we have a few cases to check:

Case 1: $3(n-1) = 2k \Rightarrow k = 3l, \; l \in \mathbb N$

$\Rightarrow n = 2l+ 1 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}(n-1) \notin \mathbb Z$

Case 2: $4k-3 = u^2, \; u \in \mathbb N$ and $u \mid 2k \Rightarrow u \mid 3(n-1)$

$4k-3 = u^2 \Rightarrow u \mid u^2 + 3 \Rightarrow u \in \{1,3\}$

$u = 1 \Rightarrow k = 1 \Rightarrow $ Rationality condition holds trivially

$u = 3 \Rightarrow k = 3 \Rightarrow $ Rationality condition holds trivially

Case 3: $u \nmid 2k \Rightarrow u \notin \{1,3\}$ but $u \mid 3(n-1) - 2k \Rightarrow u \mid 3(n-1) - \frac{u^2 + 3}{2} \Rightarrow u \mid 6(n-1) -3 $

But $u \neq 3 \Rightarrow u \mid 2(n-1) - 1$

But now at this point I can't really show that $n \in \{1,3\}$ and additionally I can't make sense of my result in case 2. It seems that for those values of $k$, then the rationality condition is just always satisfied. Did I make a mistake there?

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Two hints. It will help if you express $n$ in terms of $k$. Also if the eigenvalues of a strongly regular graph are integers, it is a conference graph and is not triangle-free if $n>5$. So $4k-3$ is a perfect square, and necessarily the square of an odd integer; hence $k=s^2+s+1$ for some integer $s$.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil Im sorry but I really cant see how I can get $n$ in terms of $k$. Effectively $n,k$ are both unrelated unknowns so how can I conclude anything beyond that $4k-3$ divides $\left[3(n-1) - 2k\right]^2$?

Comment: The eigenvalues of the graph are the valency and roots of the quadratic $t^2-(a-c)t-(k-c)=t^2+3t-(k-3)$. All parameters of the graph can written in terms of the three eigenvalues, hence in terms of $k$.

Comment: @ChrisGodsil I tried this but I still didn't manage to derive anything useful. I'm aware that the trace is $\lambda r + \mu s + k = 0 $ and $n = r + s +1$ where $\lambda, \mu$ have multiplicities $r,s$ respectively, but since these are the equations we used to derive the rationality condition, they don't convey any new information to us. Is there another relation that I'm missing?